# matomo via nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, matomo

I am having a matomo instance installed at a server1 (https://server1.com) which works fine.

I try to access server1 using nginx proxy at a subdirectory: https://server2.com/matomo/ and
I get the log form.
Once, I press login, I don't get inside matomo but I get https://server2.com/

Want to:

https://server02.com/matomo/ (proxy to server1.com) -> login -> https://server02.com/matomo/ (logged in)

What I get:

https://server02.com/matomo/ (proxy to server1.com) -> login -> https://server02.com/ (logged in to matomo but wrong url).

I have to edit the url to: https://server02.com/matomo/

My configs:

config.ini.php (matomo):

```
[general]
proxy_client_headers[] = HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
proxy_host_headers[] = HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST
```

nginx.conf:

```
location /matomo/ {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_pass https://server1.com/;
proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_buffering off;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check at: https://matomo.org/faq/how-to-install/faq_98/

#### If Matomo is behind a reverse proxy and installed in a sub-path

If you’re using Matomo behind a reverse proxy with a different path such as rewrite ^/piwik/(.*)$ /$1 break; (in nginx.conf when Matomo is installed in the /piwik path), you would need to:

1) configure your web server to provide a header HTTP_X_FORWARDED_URI. For example on NGINX, when Matomo is installed in /piwik path, you would set proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Uri /piwik; in your nginx.conf.

2) configure Matomo to read this HTTP_X_FORWARDED_URI to construct correct URLs. In Matomo config/config.ini.php in the [General] section add:

```
 [General]
 ; Use the header HTTP_X_FORWARDED_URI to construct the current script name
 proxy_uri_header = 1
```